# How to create a card hero slider that when clicked shows/hides cards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am looking to recreate a hero slider carousel similar to in this screenshot. Just looking for a starting point or any tips on how to research something like this. An example would be super helpful.
[image]

clicking into the cards will open the card & Also hide the inactive ones. It dims the inactive image slightly and only shows the small portion of the image.

sorry I don't have code to display as I am looking for an example of how to recreate what's in the image. Thanks!

the middle image in this example is the active card so the image is displayed fully with the description under it. The inactive cards only display half the image and they are dimmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("item");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("items");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  //this.classList.add("active");
    
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");  
    // If there's no active class
    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    
  this.className += " active";
  
    
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.accordion ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.accordion ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  width: 16.666%;
  height: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.accordion ul li div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion ul li div a {
  display: block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  /*padding: 15px 20px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.accordion ul li div a *:not(.bar){
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
.accordion ul li div a .bar{
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.accordion ul li div a h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-overflow: clip;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  top: 160px;
}
.accordion ul li div a p {
  top: 160px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) { background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"); background-size: 100%;background-size: cover; }
.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) { background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300"); background-size: cover;}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(3) { background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300"); background-size: cover;}
.accordion ul li.active { width: 60%; }
.accordion ul li a { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.accordion ul li.active a, .accordion ul li:hover a { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0); }
.accordion ul li.active a * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <ul id="item">
    <li class="items">
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="bar">DEMO1</span> 
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <p>Description 1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
      <div> <a href="#">
      <span class="bar">DEMO2</span>
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <p>Description 2</p>
        </a> </div>
    </li>
    <li class="items">
      <div> <a href="#">
      <span class="bar">DEMO3</span>
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
        <p>Description 3</p>
        </a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Did it turn out the way you wanted? Can you check it?

Comment: yeah that's really great actually! thank you!!!!! Do you know how I can also have the wording on the side? in the screenshot can you see the 3 words on the right of each image? @Mecit Yücetürk